# Add button to tree view group row in Odoo

Tags: odoo

Is it possible to add a button only on the grouping rows within a tree view? For example, I've created a model called `x_stock_picking_group`. Every `stock.picking` is assigned to one `x_stock_picking_group`.

Now within the tree view for pickings, I can group by "Stock Picking Group", and the tree view will divide itself into expandable rows broken down by group like this:

[image]

Apologies for the black rectangles, I'm just blocking out customer information. My question is referring to the bold black rows with the dropdown arrows, for example, the rows that say "00005", "00304", and "00005 + 00015".

Is there a way for me to access those rows within the view? I would like to add a button to each of them that will call an action for the `x_stock_picking_group`. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you found any solution ?

Comment: @AhsanAttari no I didn't. I ended up creating separate views for the `x_stock_picking_group_model` and adding the buttons and actions I needed there.